# Verify string signed with private key in iOS with C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, bluetooth-lowenergy, rsa

I am working on a bluetooth based application where I create a string in Swift and sign it with RSA private key. The string is sent to a WPF app via bluetooth. The wpf app already has its public key. I want to verify the string the in WPF app. But I am not able to do it. I am getting error for algorithm type.
Following is my Swift code:

```
func signWithPrivateKey(textToEncrypt: String) -> Data? {
    guard let privateKey: SecKey =  privateKey else {
        return nil
    }
    let algorithm: SecKeyAlgorithm = .rsaSignatureMessagePSSSHA512
    guard SecKeyIsAlgorithmSupported(privateKey, .sign, algorithm) else {
        return nil
    }
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
    let data = textToEncrypt.data(using: .utf8)!
    guard let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey,
                                                algorithm,
                                                data as CFData,
                                                &error) as Data? else {
                                                    return nil
    }
    return signature
}
```

C# code to verify the string:

```
var deferral = args.GetDeferral();

        var request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);

        byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
        reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
        Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent));
        String EncryptedMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent);
        Debug.WriteLine(text);

        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes("Guten Morgan");

            //byte[] signedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
            try
            {
                bool success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA-512"), fileContent);
                Debug.WriteLine(success);
            }catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Getting following error:

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'hashAlg')'**

I have mentioned the algorithm type as rsaSignatureMessagePSSSHA512 in Swift app and trying to verify it with SHA-512 but getting error.
Can someone please help me how to verify the signature in C#.

**Edit:**
I have modified the WPF code as following and it is not crashing now, but I am still not able to verify it

```
Credential credential = CredentialManager.ReadCredential("CredentialManagerTests");
            String publicKey = credential.Password;
            Debug.WriteLine(publicKey);
            var deferral = args.GetDeferral();

            var request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
            var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);

            byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
            reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
            string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            Debug.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(fileContent));
            
            byte[] privateKeyPkcs1DER = ConvertPKCS1PemToDer(publicKey);

            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes("Guten Morgan");
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(privateKeyPkcs1DER, out _);
                try
                {
                    bool success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, fileContent, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
                    Debug.WriteLine(success);
                }
                catch (CryptographicException e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
```

**Edit2:**
String to sent: "Guten Morgan"
Signature: "G8ePlCyPeivAHPygMHXeCTszTy9EV4y6Gsku9GQJV71t+M7ATFZjxkh9u0DVjR0ei76a4dixzgXKLZLQNy/mxwrvUvolPHE0HUFAErkzfeHcrB8/QlHlEoEdt9vf34L8KNy6yVOHWC2sytgvw009EsKUr3LYb8kSkCeaCVEEEAwAELt3z/YzfnbwR0GXatlNpmaoLOXh0mEep8Xh5AHf6RhbgS0VBFSXSbz3ALbwu5DtlaIv4P1nFOP80w2NBs7HrHOMdR0PKdgiD+suErCYWKINzToKDsdO8XNaKdw3jekYBRXl6GNfAwQeADCq0MDsvptCRVZ//fzU2fXRcaYsRA=="
Algo: SHA512

**Public Key: **
MIIBCgKCAQEA4lS13W+TXZhUXy5yB2NpeulCVb1ZSaReopeKrahjKmUx4NQxVXruEYCY3LpjZcSy8xiudVG3GBIMnPLtaMbc5WAYDj1M2OwnpNHdQ8SKtZ1tdA6iRjfOXGUa1n8FMIMKU5ynTSAiSoh+8gGrY0L6jTsCSdLO5ZU53LQFHSESM8JuBeNZozolb/cKb38ylercVeVpo8egoA8UqHezK23VUJ23faxMmMZDJxVn5pfFedxBTLxwU65KQY8Z4izaFjuPLoGe5JZkXyYNMcrYloDCBG5m9BFiXVkoLEDmGFGfWLMJcqL+D2CszqJ4h712ZR6LYRNtIbo/HG9KR7XCtap3QwIDAQAB.

Private Key:
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

**Edit3:**
My below method was wrong:

```
private byte[] ConvertPKCS1PemToDer(string pemContents)
    {
        return Convert.FromBase64String(pemContents
            .TrimStart("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----".ToCharArray())
            .TrimEnd("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----".ToCharArray())
            .Replace("\r\n", ""));
    }
```

Instead of BEGIN PUBLIC KEY it was BEGIN PRIVATE KEY.
I have fixed it as mentioned above but getting following error on Convert line in above function:

```
System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.'
```

**Edit4:**
I have now created a new project only to test my code and have added following code:

```
Private key for reference:
"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"
String publicKey = "MIIBCgKCAQEArMO9cJHbKYKkozTtqPI9fhecyiibJrvsv5KLLPlQcIi0uo6yfLD4MUFS5UbwaGATnCrLRKr27iQLWwWKxsJdEQMZDMF6EiCQSXEB2AmSEPW4NOh5kbj05cJoDrvSeac3lllsjPlOaVQSrgmiOFoJ1t98utfOJ6FCzam9DZZR7r/OwTZ0754rAp4dqwkamcTaSkW2zQhr++mw4WZZiKGJCPYKKXguGJbRTtr+dcZ4JwrvdYudCguuCVfa+1D6k0NswWEu58DELZ0XPuLu8qFiIA9MI5K/ECHXwozi8UxmDhG9NJuh+uRZZ4s7LVnkNDN8np6vhuwKNL5rP0msUciItwIDAQAB";
            String signature = "ntGm9Vx38l26ZSEitc1L+G6YZw3Dt4dmXoQQUjSAcKD1d4bFm8QI6CIncTBQ0+rGWUh7fr2DWQBB1OPgoZRoDs23SGvl+KTqUBo6Ym+kIK4KXwBrMt3YXNFpXuXVk36+4+oBPFhcMAwG4fIG5MnMEHqv/F+NNA71a10irB0frMpwpU/FZDGEbCnvOxGe6qIUsYt/dMbf1UT1AjKqQA0EmNqvIsU5DuHcpScb5xuV8aPJg6vPPKafLa8LbBiCA4dyxUcUYSjSaTQ6D9YoZ3Ich/dRBCyIdw9vESBSrOUGvwOmNl+5X+r2UyFN8RgYwW61M3iYdmkwJYYVUbMA69vCOA==";
            byte[] signatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
            using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rsa.ImportRSAPublicKey(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey), out _);
                var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
                byte[] bytesToVerify = encoder.GetBytes("Guten Morgen");

                try
                {
                    bool success = rsa.VerifyData(bytesToVerify, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512"), signatureBytes);
                    Debug.WriteLine(success);
                }
                catch (CryptographicException e)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
```

But success variable is still false.

Comment: Use `CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA512")`, i.e. omit the hyphen. Also, the Swift code seems to apply PSS padding, while the C# code uses PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. By the way, you should specify your .NET version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I have changed it and also used .rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA512 in iOS code, now my code is not crashing but I am still not able to verify the text, The success variable is still false.

Comment: can you post a unit test for the expected function?

Comment: task is WPF -> send a string to iOS -> iOS -> Receive string -> Sign with private key -> Send to WPF -> verify it with public key

Comment: In your *new* C# code you use `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256` as 3rd  parameter in `VerifyData()`, while in the Swift code you apply SHA512 (at least according to your comment: *...I have changed it and also used .rsaSignatureMessagePKCS1v15SHA512 in iOS code...*). Try to use the same digest on both sides! If there is still a problem, I recommend you to post some test data produced with the Swift code: Key pair (not a productive one), message and signature.

Comment: I had changed the Swift code but had not updated it here on StackOverflow. It is SHA256 on both sides.

Comment: @Topaco I have added the signature and the text to be transferred in Edit2, Please check my update

Comment: Sorry, but without the key pair whose private key was used to create the signature for the message, no analysis is feasible.

Comment: @Topaco I have added the keys

Comment: Both posted keys do not belong together, they differ in the modulus! Check this with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js and double check your keys! Also, the posted private key produces a different signature (checked with Java; note PKCS#1 v1.5 signatures are deterministic). Thus, if the Swift code for the posted private key really creates the posted signature, the Swift code is buggy. Furthermore, the posted signature cannot be verified with the posted public key either (checked with Java), i.e. the C# code returns a correct result.

Comment: @Topaco I have checked my code in Swift, I tried to sign it with private key and verify with the public key it works fine(in iOS code). I am using the same pair of keys. But it is not working in C#

Comment: Also will it possible for you to share how to use this lapo.it? I am sorry this is new for me. When I enter my key string there it generates some bytes but I am not able to make any sense out of it

Comment: So there is no misunderstanding: If you use the Swift code to create the signature of _Guten Morgan_ with the *posted* private key _MIIEow...O/YGGX_ then you get the *posted* signature _bje2...BA==_? And if you use the Swift code to verify this signature with the *posted* public key _MIIBCg...IDAQAB_, then the verification is successful?

Comment: There is not much to say about https://lapo.it/asn1js. Put the keys (one by one) into the input area and press *decode*, then you will see the individual key parameters. The modulus is the top 2048 bit integer value, the public exponent is the 65537 value.

Comment: Yes it works in Swift with the above keys. Please see my latest edit, I have found another mistake in my code

Comment: The public key and the private key are not related. A signature created with the private key cannot be verified with the public key. If the Swift code does this, it will not work properly. You can verify this with online tools, e.g. https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp. I'm afraid I can't help you here.

Comment: @Topaco I have created a new project and regenerated the keys also. Please check my Edit4, keys should be correct now. I have checked the keys in lapo.it link shared by you and tried to match the Modulus as told by you. It looks same now. There is no crash but the signature is still not verified

Comment: You have to Base64 decode the signature of course (and not UTF8 encode). Then it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ElU67S

Comment: Thanks Topaco, it helped me fix my issue.